# Is it possible and how to recover deleted/erased and overwrited data from hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, microsoft-outlook, data-recovery, file-recovery

Windows8, 2.5" hdd, d:\ ntfs partition, file in need 9GB archive.pst

Archive was **deleted** by mistake. Instead of recovering/undeleting that archive, we copied one from all mighty but very old and wrong backup. That process probably **overwrite** original archive.

**Nothing was written on d:\ partition after wrong backup.**

I have tried recuva, avira recovery, Active unerase/undelete, Get data back, and some more free and commercial apps. Used both simple and raw search mode. Wasted 4 days...

I have not recovered much needed archive.pst

My two questions:
1. Is it possible to recover overwritten data?
2. How? What should I use/buy from software and or hardware?

Comment: Try file recovery software of your choice.  If it can be recovered it will be don't write anymore data to the drive every single bit increases the chance if no recovery

Comment: if the data is overwritten, it is not likely that it can be recovered, even by professionals. perhaps if they run a lab with a clean room, and remove each platter for analysis, but research has indicated that even one overwrite is sufficient to permenantly destroy data.

Comment: Rahmound: yes I know that. As mentioned in question I have tried more than 7 recovery apps. Shakehar: No duplicate. HDD was not remover, magnetised, abused... @Frank Thomas: unfortunately that was my opinion also, but I really hoped I was wrong. Thank you for confirmation.

Comment: I don't wanna publicize my blog but I had written on this here http://tiptogeek.com/recover-permanently-deleted-files

Comment: @Partih Parikh: Thanks, Have not tried Puran yet. What are your experiences with overwritten files?

Answer (score 1):

straight off the bat - if you have managed to overwrite the file, the data is most likely not there for you to recover without specialist software.  Imagine the 1's and 0's on your drive as a pack of playing cards spread out in a row.  If you write new data, you start flipping cards over from 1 to 0 (face up to down) and the original pattern is lost.. and for those of you hot on your TV series, yes that analogy came from Numb3rs.

As for recovering your data - this site isnt really for product recommendations and may be closed as off topic - but in my opinion and experience, I have had great success with [Easus DRW (Data Recovery Wizard)](http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizardpro/).  There is a free edition which will recover some bits, but the pro version is worth every penny.  I've used it to recover all sorts over the years and I've not hit anything it couldn't find - yet!

Also - in the meantime - stop using the drive - dont make any more writes to it or you risk further damaging your recovery potential.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried Edrw. It found 45gb of archives. I copied them all to usb hdd, tried them all, but unfortunately all of them was old backups. The same we have on server.